# sidebar region invisible for administrator drupal7

Tags: theming

`region--sidebar_second.tpl.php` is my sidebar template page, which contains the html structure for sidebar region. This sidebar region is visible for anonymous user and sidebar region is empty when log in as administrator.

Checked the permissions section, but there is no sidebar section settings there. What is the reason for sidebar region to be invisible for admin user?

Comment: Is admin user is the user with uid `1` ?

Comment: yes. administrator uid is 1

Comment: check 'Visibility settings ' of your block which is assigned to sidebar region. And ensure any option given for 'Show block for specific roles '

Comment: No. I haven't selected any roles in the "show block for specific roles" section.

Comment: Are you using the same theme for administrator and anonymous users ? If not please make sure the block is enabled in your admin theme.

Comment: Previously it was different theme for each anonymous and administrator. Now i'm using the same theme for both users. but still, the sidebar is invisible for admin user. cleared all caches.